# Sql Server 2008 table join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written one query in SQL. I can't get correct output.

here I have attached screenshot.

This is query Output

[image: This is query Output]

but I want it like this

[image]

Comment: use `row_numer`

Comment: Please post the code as text, don't post an image of it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `union` subquery (unless you need to remove duplicates).  This should do what you want:

```
select max(case when status = 'O' then ref end) as O,
       max(case when status = 'E' then ref end) as E,
       max(case when status = 'A' then ref end) as A       
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by status order by status) as seqnum
      from nl_pmnt
      where status in ('O', 'E', 'A')
     ) p
group by seqnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select [O],[E],[A] from (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) [RN], ref [O] from nl_pmnt where [status] = 'O' and ref <> ''
) [O] left join (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) [RN], ref [E] from nl_pmnt where [status] = 'O' and ref <> ''
) [E] on [O].[RN] = [E].[RN] left join (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) [RN], ref [A] from nl_pmnt where [status] = 'O' and ref <> ''
) [A] on [O].[RN] = [A].[RN]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT

```
SELECT [O],[E],[A] FROM (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY status ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN, ref, status from nl_pmnt
    where ref <> '') SRC
PIVOT(MAX(ref) FOR status IN ([O],[E],[A])) PVT
```